# How to add styles to the datatable

Tags: c#

Using CSharp, how can I set the width, height, border color etc to the datatable. I want to add some features to the table which gives the look cool.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (myQuantity[i]!=null && myQuantity[i].Length>0)
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = myName[i];
            row["Quantity"] = myQuantity[i];
            row["Price"] = myPrice[i];

            c = Convert.ToInt32(myQuantity[i]);

            int price = Convert.ToInt32(myPrice[i]) * c;


            row["Amount"] = price;
            // row["ImageUrlPath"] = "~/Images/cross.png";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

        }
    }

  //  dt.Rows[0].Delete();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();


}
```

Comment: do you mean styling the gridview that has its data source in the datatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this on the DataTable but you can on the Row of the GridView

**Example :**

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{            
   e.Row.CssClass="your css class";
}
}
```